# SQL Update NULL value from select statement query

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to posting on this site, but been using it for a while to get assistance to SQL queries.
I have an issue that I'm trying to resolve. I have 2 columns in a query which are machine and ID, for some machines the ID will be NULL, but for others they will have an ID value as set out below.

```
Machine   ID
test1     3
test12    NULL
test3     4
test4     NULL
```

As the ID's will be present in the table, I need to update the NULL values, if the machine name is like the one which has a value, for example test 1 and test12 both should have ID 3, but test12 is showing NULL. What I want to be able to do is to replace the NULL for test12 with ID = 3, as the machine names are similar.

I have tried COALESCE, ISNULL and CASE, which all will update the values, but I need know the value, but I wont know it until I have done the select statement. 
Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

Comment: "as the machine names are similar." - *define* similar. What, specifically, are the criteria for deciding that two machine names are similar? Is it just prefix based? If so, is it symmetrical (I.e. test56 has an ID, test5 doesn't. Does that count as a match)?

Comment: The machine name will all be for example AB-CDE-L123 format. So for example, AB-CDE-L124 will have an ID for 43, where AB-CDE-L125 will have a NULL ID. What I want to do is set the ID from  AB-CDE-L124 which is 43 to AB-CDE-L125, replacing the NULL with 43.

Comment: Don't expect us to divine the rules from examples. Be specific, formulate the *actual* rules for us to be able to take any two strings and be able to work out "yes, these are similar, by Bretty's rules" or "no, these are not similar". Then edit your question to include these rules.

Comment: Read @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment again. Still same question, how do you decide names are *similar*?  AB-CDE-L124 and AB-CDE-L125 are similar on what basis? U mean all AB-CDE-L12* are similar? That would make AB-CDE-L12 and AB-CDE-L124 similar, while AB-CDE-L12 would be similar to AB-CDE-L1 too. That does not make sense, right!

Comment: The name is similar from the second - for example AB-CDE-L12 and AB-CDE-L1 are both similar and should matched on this example, but AB-CCE-L123 isn't similar at all and will have a different ID completely. Make sense?

Comment: No, because based on your rule, AB-CDE-L1 ~ AB-CDE-L12 ~AB-CDE-L123 all fit the same pattern of similarity.

Also, What if you have AB-CDE-L10 || NULL, AB-CDE-L11 || 5 AND AB-CDE-L12 || NULL?  *-L12 is similar to both a NULL and 5.  Which is it?

Comment: Very poor clarity on your requirement. As people have said you need to be able to explain EACH AND EVERY scenario for them so that they can write code to account for all scenarios. Simply saying ...1 is like ...12 is not clear enough.

Comment: There will be a number of records in the table, they are grouped by the letter before and after the '-' i.e. AB-CDE-L111, AB-CDE-L112, AB-CDE-L113, AB-CDE-L124, AB-CDE-L116 all of these should have in the query an ID of 45. The next set of machines will be AB-CCC-L111, AB-CCC-L112, AB-CCC-L115 all of these should have in the query an ID of 47 and finally there will be the last set of machine, AB-BBB-L113, AB-BBB-L144, AB-BBB-L115, AB-BBB-L120 all of these should have in the query an ID of 50. In the query, a machine returns a NULL ID then I need to update the query results, not the table.

Comment: @Bretty73 - based on your latest comments I've amended my answer, although I'm still slightly unclear as to whether you need a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements in your last comment:

> There will be a number of records in the table, they are grouped by the letter before and after the '-' i.e. AB-CDE-L111, AB-CDE-L112, AB-CDE-L113, AB-CDE-L124, AB-CDE-L116 all of these should have in the query an ID of 45. The next set of machines will be AB-CCC-L111, AB-CCC-L112, AB-CCC-L115 all of these should have in the query an ID of 47 and finally there will be the last set of machine, AB-BBB-L113, AB-BBB-L144, AB-BBB-L115, AB-BBB-L120 all of these should have in the query an ID of 50. In the query, a machine returns a NULL ID then I need to update the query results, not the table.

So a `SELECT` query to get you your results would be:

```
declare @machine table  (Machine varchar(30) not null, ID int null)

insert into @machine
values ('AB-CDE-L111',     NULL),
('AB-CDE-L112',    NULL),
('AB-CDE-L113',     45),
('AB-CDE-L124',     NULL),
('AB-CDE-L116', NULL),
('AB-CCC-L111',     NULL),
('AB-CCC-L112',    NULL),
('AB-CCC-L113',     47),
('AB-CCC-L124',     NULL),
('AB-CCC-L116', NULL),
('AB-BBB-L111',     NULL),
('AB-BBB-L112',    NULL),
('AB-BBB-L113',     50),
('AB-BBB-L124',     NULL),
('AB-BBB-L116', NULL)

select m1.Machine, m2.ID
from @machine m1
inner join @machine m2
on m2.ID is not null
and left(m2.Machine, 6) = left(m1.Machine, 6)
order by m1.Machine
```

This assumes that:

1) There is always the same amount of characters making up the prefix to the machine code.

2) That there is only one Machine in each group that has been assigned an ID.

If either of these assumptions is wrong then you may need to do extra string manipulation in the case of 1) and use some kind of function (`ROW_NUMBER` etc.) in the case of 2) to avoid duplicate rows (although you could just use `SELECT DISTINCT` if the `ID`s would be the same).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments you will have to work out your match formula and specify it in the join condition.  I believe the query you are looking for is:

```
Create Table Machines (Name Varchar(8000), ID Int)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test1', 3)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test12', Null)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test3', 4)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test4', Null)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test89', Null)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test8', 5)
Insert Into Machines Values ('test64', Null)

Update M1 Set M1.ID = M2.ID
    From Machines M1
    Join (Select Left(Name,5) NamePrefix, Max(ID) ID 
            From Machines 
            Where ID Is Not Null 
            Group By Left(Name,5)) M2
     On Left(M1.Name, 5) = M2.NamePrefix
     Where M1.ID Is Null

Select * From Machines
```

Note that I used a group by in the joined query in case multiple rows match and we only want one value returned. You can use window functions or other logic instead of the group by if you want to pick specifically which match is chosen.